# How to display treeview in view using cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye6kX.png)Hi guys i have problem to display treeview display in cakephp 2...using same table as parents and child as relationship.

**Table MediaDirectory**

| id | Title | Parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | null |
| 2 | Test 2 | null |
| 3 | Test 3 | 1 |
| 4 | Test 4 | 1 |
| 5 | Test 5 | 3 |
| 6 | Test 6 | 2 |
| 7 | Test 7 | 2 |

**ContentsController.php**

```php
public function index()
{
    $Treeview = $this->MediaDirectory->find("all", 
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'MediaDirectory.parent_id' => null
            )
        )
    );
    
    $this->set(compact('$Treeview'));
}
```

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I don't understand how can you have 2 times a field named parent_id in your table. You should remove the one which is null.
You need 3 differents fields in your table :

- **parent_id** to store the id of the parent object.
- **lft** to store the lft value of the current row.
- **rght** to store the rght value of the current row.

Then you need to add the following line in your model :

```
public $actsAs = array('Tree');
```

If you want that it to work, you have to insert your data using your controller. lft and rght are automatically defined by the core when you save some data in it.

For instance, in your controller

```
$data['MediaDirectory']['parent_id'] = 10;
$data['MediaDirectory']['title'] = 'Test 1';
$this->MediaDirectory->save($data);
```

And after that you should replace your code in your controller like this :

```
public function index() {
  $Treeview = $this->MediaDirectory->find("threaded", 
    array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'MediaDirectory.parent_id'=> null,
        'MediaDirectory.fk_id'=> $cid // Not sure what this is suppose to do
      )
    )
  );
  $this->set(compact('Treeview')); // TreeviewChild name was wrong
}
```

The query build **find("threaded")** is suppose to return tree data. Do not hesitate to use debug() function to visualize what data you are currently manipulating.

Everything you need is there about the version 2.x : https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

Comment: hi sir how to display in view the treeview